# spring cloud kafka streams terminating in azure kubernetes service

Tags: azure, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I created Kafka streams application with spring cloud stream which reads data from one topic and writes to another topic and I'm trying to deploy and run the job in AKS with ACR image but the stream getting closed without any error after reading all the available messages(lag 0) in the topic. strange thing I'm facing is, it is running fine in Intellj.

Here is my AKS pod logs:

```
2021-03-02 17:30:39,131] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:840] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Received FETCH response from node 3 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=11, clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, correlationId=62): org.apache.kafka.common.requests.FetchResponse@7b021a01
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,131] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler FetchSessionHandler.java:463] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Node 0 sent an incremental fetch response with throttleTimeMs = 3 for session 614342128 with 0 response partition(s), 1 implied partition(s)
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,132] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher Fetcher.java:1177] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition test.topic at position FetchPosition{offset=128, offsetEpoch=Optional[0], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[vm3.lab (id: 3 rack: 1)], epoch=1}} to node vm3.lab (id: 3 rack: 1)
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,132] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler FetchSessionHandler.java:259] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=614342128, epoch=49) for node 3. Added 0 partition(s), altered 0 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,132] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher Fetcher.java:261] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(), toForget=(), implied=(test.topic)) to broker vm3.lab (id: 3 rack: 1)
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,132] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:505] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=11, clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, correlationId=63) and timeout 60000 to node 3: {replica_id=-1,max_wait_time=500,min_bytes=1,max_bytes=52428800,isolation_level=0,session_id=614342128,session_epoch=49,topics=[],forgotten_topics_data=[],rack_id=}
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,636] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:840] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Received FETCH response from node 3 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=11, clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, correlationId=63): org.apache.kafka.common.requests.FetchResponse@50fb365c
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,636] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler FetchSessionHandler.java:463] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Node 0 sent an incremental fetch response with throttleTimeMs = 3 for session 614342128 with 0 response partition(s), 1 implied partition(s)
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,637] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher Fetcher.java:1177] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition test.topic at position FetchPosition{offset=128, offsetEpoch=Optional[0], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[vm3.lab (id: 3 rack: 1)], epoch=1}} to node vm3.lab (id: 3 rack: 1)
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,637] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler FetchSessionHandler.java:259] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=614342128, epoch=50) for node 3. Added 0 partition(s), altered 0 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,637] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher Fetcher.java:261] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(), toForget=(), implied=(test.topic)) to broker vm3.lab (id: 3 rack: 1)
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,637] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:505] [Consumer clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=latest] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=11, clientId=latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1-consumer, correlationId=64) and timeout 60000 to node 3: {replica_id=-1,max_wait_time=500,min_bytes=1,max_bytes=52428800,isolation_level=0,session_id=614342128,session_epoch=50,topics=[],forgotten_topics_data=[],rack_id=}
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,710] [DEBUG] [SpringContextShutdownHook] [o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006] Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@dc9876b, started on Tue Mar 02 17:29:08 GMT 2021
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,715] [DEBUG] [SpringContextShutdownHook] [o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006] Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@71391b3f, started on Tue Mar 02 17:29:12 GMT 2021, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@dc9876b
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,718] [DEBUG] [SpringContextShutdownHook] [o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:369] Stopping beans in phase 2147483547
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,718] [DEBUG] [SpringContextShutdownHook] [o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:242] Bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry' completed its stop procedure
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,719] [DEBUG] [SpringContextShutdownHook] [o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams KafkaStreams.java:1016] stream-client [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e] Stopping Streams client with timeoutMillis = 10000 ms.
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,719] [INFO] [SpringContextShutdownHook] [o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams KafkaStreams.java:287] stream-client [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,729] [INFO] [kafka-streams-close-thread] [o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread StreamThread.java:1116] stream-thread [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] Informed to shut down
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,729] [INFO] [kafka-streams-close-thread] [o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread StreamThread.java:221] stream-thread [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,788] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread StreamThread.java:772] stream-thread [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] State already transits to PENDING_SHUTDOWN, skipping the run once call after poll request
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,788] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread StreamThread.java:206] stream-thread [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] Ignoring request to transit from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to PENDING_SHUTDOWN: only DEAD state is a valid next state
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,788] [INFO] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread StreamThread.java:1130] stream-thread [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
[2021-03-02 17:30:39,788] [DEBUG] [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.s.p.i.AssignedStreamsTasks AssignedStreamsTasks.java:529] stream-thread [latest-e07d649d-5178-4107-898b-08b8008d822e-StreamThread-1] Clean shutdown of all active tasks
```

Please advise.

Comment: Something is closing the application context `Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4c5ae43b,` Add the thread name to your logging config to see if it provides any clues.

Comment: @GaryRussell I added thread name but didn't get information about why it's closing.

Comment: Edit the question to show the new log.

Comment: @GaryRussell I did Thanks

Comment: `[SpringContextShutdownHook]` - this means the JVM shutdown hook registered by Boot is closing the application context - this will happen whenever the JVM is stopped normally, e.g. `System.exit()`, `kill 15` etc. Might be pretty tough to track down the root cause.

Comment: I'm getting this issue only in the k8s run. are you aware of any configuration in K8S that making the context close? @GaryRussell.

Comment: I am not; sorry. The close is a side effect of the JVM being shut down for some reason.